# Android, OpenGL ES 2.0, ndk - glCheckFramebufferStatus returning GL_FRAMEBUFFER_UNSUPPORTED

Tags: android, c++, opengl, opengl-es, android-ndk

I'm in the process of porting a game, written in C++ (with SDL), to Android. I've done it before with an older project on a wing and a prayer (with some previous help from stackoverflow!), but although the result was a bit sloppy, it worked on pretty much every Android device I threw it at.

At the time I was too tired to refactor and simplify what I had. This time I'm creating an engine that *in theory* I won't have to touch again, and I'm bringing my old code across. While I've got everything compiling and running, it's not rendering anything.

Specifically, OpenGL ES 2.0 is throwing up a GL_FRAMEBUFFER_UNSUPPORTED message. I draw everything to a texture (it *was* 320x240 - that'll change eventually), and then draw that texture so that it covers the screen. It's refusing to draw to that texture - I can draw directly to the screen (which at least gives me hope the shaders are fine), but that's not very helpful.

My framebuffer code looks a bit like this:

```
_superDuperFrameBuffer = 0;
_depthRenderBuffer = 0;

glGenFramebuffers(1, &_superDuperFrameBuffer);

//-----

glGenTextures(1, &_screenTexture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _screenTexture);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, SCREENWIDTH2, SCREENHEIGHT2, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL); //float?

glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

if(_currentWidth < SCREENWIDTH2*2 || _currentHeight < SCREENHEIGHT2*2) {
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
}
else {
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
}
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);


glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

//-----

glGenRenderbuffers(1, &_depthRenderBuffer);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, _depthRenderBuffer);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, SCREENWIDTH2, SCREENHEIGHT2);

glGenRenderbuffers(1, &_stencilRenderBuffer);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, _stencilRenderBuffer);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_STENCIL_INDEX8, SCREENWIDTH2, SCREENHEIGHT2);


glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, _superDuperFrameBuffer);

glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,      GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,   GL_TEXTURE_2D,      _screenTexture, 0); 
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,   GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT,    GL_RENDERBUFFER,    _depthRenderBuffer);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,   GL_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT,  GL_RENDERBUFFER,    _stencilRenderBuffer);


GLenum status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
if(status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, "LOG", "FRAMEBUFFER BORK %x", status);
}
```

Is there something obvious I'm doing wrong here? It's a simple 2D game - nothing fancy, and it all seemingly worked before. I don't know what the best settings are for Android - there's not really anything out there to explain how to do things properly.

From what I'm reading, GL_FRAMEBUFFER_UNSUPPORTED is supposed to turn up when one of the settings disagrees with another, or if the device doesn't support framebuffers (which I know it does, because my last game worked well enough!)

Also concerned code might not be getting cleaned up properly - once or twice earlier versions have shown signs of life, but after restarting the game, they haven't. I haven't ruled out the idea that there's an outside influence messing with things, but I figured I'd check to see if the above code was correct first.

Testing on a 2013 Nexus 7.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does it pass the test if you attach only the color buffer?

Comment: My hunch would be that you need a combined DEPTH_STENCIL format instead of separate ones.

Comment: With just the colour buffer it does pass, but is missing depth and stencil buffers going to cause problems down the line?

Comment: That was just for diagnostics. BTW, you can use the @username notation to notify people when you respond to their comments. I hadn't seen the additional information until now.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in a comment, the framebuffer works without the depth and stencil renderbuffers bound. This is a common problem with GL[ES], because there is no method of querying supported combinations and/or formats. You've just got to try it and see if it works - and if it doesn't, the actual problem is not always clear. From the [GLES 2.0 spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/es_cm_spec_2.0.24.pdf):

> 4.1 Per-Fragment Operations
> All OpenGL 2.0 per-fragment operations are supported, except for occlusion queries, logic-ops, alpha test
> and color index related operations. Depth and stencil operations are supported, but a selected config is not
> required to include a depth or stencil buffer with the caveat that an OpenGL ES 2.0 implementation must
> support at least one config with a depth bit depth of 16 or higher and a stencil bit depth of 8 or higher.

However, it does not require any specific depth and/or stencil format or combination thereof. The [glCheckFramebufferStatus manpage](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glCheckFramebufferStatus.xml) states:

> GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16 is the only depth-renderable format. GL_STENCIL_INDEX8 is the only stencil-renderable format.

This statement can (and is) modified by extensions. It also doesn't explicitly state that the two in combination necessarily form a valid combination which will cause `glCheckFramebufferStatus` to report success, and in some drivers, they do not (Adreno 320 may be one of those).

The fact is that many (most) Android GPUs support the [GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_packed_depth_stencil.txt) extension, which provides the `DEPTH24_STENCIL8_OES` format, so if this extension is available, `DEPTH24_STENCIL8_OES` should be preferred over a `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16` and `GL_STENCIL_INDEX8` combination, as it is definitely supported with that driver. A renderbuffer created with this format should be bound to both the `GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT` and `GL_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT` (simultaneously). This extension became standard in GLES 3.0, meaning that every GLES 3.0 capable device should have it.

Of course, if you don't *need* the depth/stencil attachments, then, they are just a waste of memory, and you shouldn't use them. Although, if you are just porting arbitrary rendering code, it's probably safer to have them bound.